Trimming a video using FFmpeg leads to black screen
I try to figure out how to use FFmpeg to trim videos. I have created a 30 second .mov screen capture using Apple's QuickTime player, and then tried to trim it using three different ways:

Using -copyts, without re-encoding
ffmpeg -copyts -ss 00:00:10 -i input.mov -to 00:00:15 -map 0 -c copy output.mov


Using -copyts, with re-encoding
ffmpeg -copyts -ss 00:00:10 -i input.mov -to 00:00:15 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a aac -b:a 192k output.mov


Using -trim (with re-encoding, which is the only option):
ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf trim=10:15 output.mov



No matter which approach I tried, the output video is always 15 seconds long and the first 10 seconds of that is just a black screen, whereas what I expected is a 5-second video and without the black screen.
All the three solutions are from here: Cut part from video file from start position to end position with FFmpeg (answers by @slhck and @malat), and are very high-voted, so I expect they should work without issues, but they don't. Why is that? Is there a problem with the commands, or with the video?
The video is uploaded here: https://github.com/jsx97/test/blob/main/input.mov

All three work fine for me. Might be your player, or an issue with  your version of ffmpeg. Incidently, the file has no audio, so second option does not require audio parameters.

@Sark Which player you use? "All three work fine for me." - You mean there is no "black screen"?

@jax97...MPC-HC and no black screen. Try trim=10:15,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS 
for third script.

@Sark Yes, this fixed the "black screen" problem. But why does it work for one player and not for another? Does it mean that using setpts=PTS-STARTPTS is a recommended practice, which is often overlooked?

@jax97. Different player decoders, or different player parameter settings perhaps. Universal compatibility is never guaranteed. And yes, setpts can often  get you out of a hole when altering timestamps.

@Sark What I want is simply to figure out how to trim videos. This is very surpising to me that this task doesn't have (or maybe it does, but I'm not aware of it yet...) single solution that will "just works" for any player, codec, and whatever.

@jax97. So many different ways of doing this. Reencoding is usually the most reliable method. Cutting on key frames in copy mode is a close second. The basic method I use is ffmpeg -i input.mov -ss 10 -to 15 output.mov. You can add encoding parameters before the output if the defaults don't suit.... Edit: Input before time range should be frame accurate, after produces faster seek times, but may not be frame accurate.

@Sark 1. Input before time range should be frame accurate, after produces faster seek times, but may not be frame accurate. - Do you mean that ffmpeg -ss [start] -i input.mov -to [duration] output.mov is more frame accurate than ffmpeg -i input.mov -ss [start] -to [end] output.mov? 2. Do you know why in the first version the value of the -to option works as "end", but in the second version it works as "duration"? Thanks for you help by the way, it is much appreciated!

I recommend you to first try without re-encoding (using -c copy), without -copyts (so that the timestamp of the first output frames starts from zero), and with -t 5 instead of -to 15: ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:10 -i input.mov -t 5 -c copy output.mov. In case it's not working, try the other solutions. The reason for the black screen is that the timestamp of the first frame is 10.0 (seconds) due to -copyts, and not zero. We may check the PTS timestamps using FFprobe: ffprobe -select_streams v -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -show_entries frame=pts_time output.mov.

@Sark Thanks! But do you know the answer to the question #2 above? The commands are exactly the same except the order, but in the first command -to works as "end", whereas in the second it works as "duration". So confusing to me.

@jax97..Firstly, Rotem responded after your last comment, not me. Secondly, your comment got the scripts the wrong way round. If the time range follows the input it should be frame accurate. Not sure why -to set duration for you, it shouldn't. Are you sure you didn't omit the "o" by accident. -t sets duration.

@jax97. I think I know what you may have done. If you place the input between the start and end time thus: -ss 10 -i input.mov -to 15. The -to defaults to duration. Don't ask me why.
